# Can I claim a tax deduction for college tuition paid but was then reimbursed by my company?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, tuition

I paid the college tuition for my kid with my credit card and I have received the corresponding form for the tax deduction from the college.

However, my employer has the benefit to cover the fee. In other words, all tuition has been reimbursed by the company.

So in this case, can I still claim the tuition for tax deducted for year 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to being able to deduct tuition is to have actual  expenses that are on the approved list. If the employer is covering the expenses, then you don't have any tuition payment to deduct.

You might have other expenses that were not covered by the employer. This could include fees (besides tuition), room, board, books. If the expenses are deductible can depend on if these costs came from your funds, or from a 529 plan.

Here is information on the [deduction](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch06.html#en_US_2013_publink1000295026), the tax [credit](http://www.irs.gov/uac/American-Opportunity-Tax-Credit%3a-Questions-and-Answers) and [529 plans](http://www.irs.gov/uac/529-Plans%3a-Questions-and-Answers).

You might even have to pay [taxes on the benefit](http://www.irs.com/articles/will-i-be-taxed-employer-tuition-assistance).